# Parameters URL with DRF routers

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework for created a API. In this project i want to capture parameters in the URL. For example i want to capture the username and password of a user and my idea is like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?unsername=username&password=password
```

But i cant, I' usin routers and django-filter, but i cant get the parameters url. My project files are there:

view.py:

```
class AccountsData(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.UserData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AccountsDataSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ['username', 'password']

    lookup_url_kwarg = 'username'

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True, url_name='login', url_path='login')
    def login(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({"Login successfully"}, 200)
```

urls.py:

```
from api import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', views.AccountsData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request query parameters have nothing to do with routing, they are passed with the request independently of how you configure the route. You have access to them in `request.query_params`, for example, `request.query_params.get('username')` would get the value of the `username` parameter.

Being said that, your idea has a terrible mistake: password or any kind of confidential data should NEVER go in query parameters, you should use an http verb that carries the data in its body (POST, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new to creating APIs, so there are many things I don't know.

Comment: No problem, we're all learning, but always keep an eye on security ;)